# C# CMD - Application stdout | Application2 stdin (Trying to do normal pipe like this)

Tags: c#, windows

Well simply put, trying to do a normal command line where you use one application which will take something, output that to stdout (i think?) which you then in the same command can use within another application.

Something like:

```
Audiodecoder "Audio.mp3" - | AudioEncoder "-" "NewAudio.aac"
```

(Let's say that the AudioEncoder can Only handle PCM, and Audiodecoder decodes realtime).

This is very normal in these situations, encoding and similar stuff.

And as you can see, it's very simple, you " left | right" and done.

However, i am Not able to make it in C#, i tried using cmd and write exactly the same (Even with /C at start), but it won't work, it simply says "16bit compatibility blabla" when it reaches the other application after the "|" symbol.

I also tried running the pipe application "audiodecoder" directly and do the same commands (Except /C and Audiodecoder.exe of course), but nothing there either.

I tried reading up on this, but i only find stuff about redirecting and working with stdin/out through events, but i don't want to do something fancy, it's just simply output/input , can't see that it's that much harder when doing it in C# compared to cmd.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the tool:

https://github.com/chikuzen/avs2pipemod/

I am trying to use that to feed an Avisynth Script to Opus.
Not sure if that matters as all piping should be fairly similar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is something along these lines.

```
Process compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "Audiodecoder.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "Audio.mp3 -"; // I assume the dash is needed?
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // Redirect to the Console.
compiler.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();

// Run next pass.
compiler = new Process();
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "Audiodecoder.exe";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "\" - \" NewAudio.aac";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // Redirect to the Console.
compiler.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

compiler.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Don't work. Not sure what it's supposed to do, both are just reading the ouput, shouldn't one Read and other Write what's being read in async?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you wanting to execute something, and read back the results? It sounded like you wanted to execute a command and capture the output, then execute a follow up.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how it works, but from my understanding it's something like this. Application1 writes to a buffer, Application 2 reads from it, and both are in sync so they can keep writing to each other, not just One Big Buffer if you get what i mean. In CMD this is super easy and automatic as long as the application as it set for you, so i don't see any reason for it to be a mess in C# as i simply want to Call CMD. Worth noting is that running a .bat as the Command file works like it would normally, it's just running the process itself within C#.